# Robolectric test never finishes

Tags: android, robolectric

I am using Robolectric 3.8 to start an activity with an intent and then test that the layout has been set correctly.

This is my test code:

```
Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyModuleActivity.class, intent).create().visible().get();
Switch inputSwitch = (Switch)activity.findViewById(R.id.input_status_switch);
assertFalse("Switch should be off to start", inputSwitch.isChecked());
```

I am using the .visible() call as described in [Robolectric: Driving the Activity Lifecycle](http://robolectric.org/activity-lifecycle/) otherwise the activity.findViewById returns null.

I have tested other similar activities in my project and they work fine. I am sure that setContentView() is called in the onCreate method.

My other test (without the .visible()) works fine:

```
Activity inputActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(InputModuleActivity.class).create().get();
assertThat(ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast(), equalTo("Unable to load config"));
```